# How To transfer data from one production server to another

Tags: sql-server, database, database-migration

I have to migrate whole SQL Server database from one production server to another production server. I do not have access to live database. But of course I have create tables script. Suppose I create database on new server and I run create tables script, so empty database will all empty tables will be created. How can I transfer data from one production server to another.

Is there any tool in SQL Server to create scripts to transfer data from all tables from one server to another? In my situation I will need to create script to transfer the data and give it some other person so after running that script all data will be transferred.

Thank you.

Comment: SQL Server has a LOT of technologies to handle data replication or transfer, and entire chapters in the Books Online that explain what each technology is for. We can't "suppose" what you want to do, you have to be specific. Replication is good for continuous publishing of data. ETL jobs are good for one-offs. You could even use a brute-force backup/restore to transfer an entire database

Comment: ....Or do a database backup.. However, not possible if not having access to the database...
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/backup-restore/restore-a-database-to-a-new-location-sql-server

Comment: BTW data scripting or dumps is rarely used because it can break *very* easily, and performance is attrocious especially if you have a moderate amount of data

Comment: Another option, export the data with BCP, transfer it to the other server and bulk import it with BCP or BULK INSERT. For 1000 rows, this can be even 1000 times faster. For 10K, probably 100K faster. The reason is that individual inserts are individually logged  transactions. A BULK INSERT though can be a single transaction that uses minimal logging

Comment: You could also *detach* the database from one server, copy the files to the other server and attach it there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [generate scripts for data](http://www.kodyaz.com/sql-server-2012/how-to-script-data-in-sql-server-2012.aspx) too just like database objects on SQL Server
Please refer to given link for how you can script data in SQL Server database.

On database, you can choose on context menu "**Tasks > Generate Scripts**" option

In Advanced Scripting options, you can see three options in type of data to script. You can choose **Data only** script type

I hope it helps